# Cannot read property 'history' of undefined when setting up a useHistory hook

Tags: reactjs, electron, react-hooks

The error I'm getting is `Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`. I have correctly imported the `useHistory()` hook from `react-router-dom`.

```
export const App = () => {
  
  /* Handle deep link navigation based on incoming myApp://entity/:entity_id call */
  const history = useHistory()

  const setLocationFromDeepLink = (path: string) => {
    history.push(`/${path}`)
  }

.......
```

Comment: A lot of the detail of this question was removed after an answer was received. Could the below answer still have been given at this level of detail? I don't know React in order to determine if this is still answerable, but I wonder if some of the excised detail might be useful.

Comment: Yes, I realised the original question was kind of irrelevant to the actual problem I was facing, which was answered perfectly by the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that you are using BrowserRouter from react-router-dom
because useHistory() works only with BrowserRouter.

```
import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
```

```
<BrowserRouter>
        ...
         Do logic here
        ...
 </BrowserRouter>
```

You can learn more about react-router-dom from below link

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks